# How to allow only numbers to be filled into input ref with class name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How to allow only `numbers` to get filled into input ref with class name using javascript ?

I test my code but not work ,

thank you for help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function input_format()
{
    $(.number).val($(.number).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
    if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="number" class="number" name="number" onkeypress="input_format()" onblur="input_format()">
```

Comment: why don't you use `input type="number"`

Comment: it should be $(".number") and not $(.number)

Comment: @  Kartikeya -- IE old version not support.

Comment: this question has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Comment: @ Anoop Joshi -  not work.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @CerlinBoss - on my code , user can fill char and num into input.

but i want to apply for can fill only number.

Comment: i asked, do you get any error in console? like something is not defined

Comment: @CerlinBoss - no i don't get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

you need to pass the event as an argument

```
onkeypress="input_format(event)"
```

Then your function will be look like

```
function input_format(event)
{
```

Also you need to wrap the classsname with quotes like this

```
$(".number").
```

Your final code will look like

```
function input_format(event) {
    $(".number").val($(".number").val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
    if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/Fp4sJ/811/)

Answer (score 1):

Try it !

```js
   function numberOnly(event){
      var chCode = (event.charCode === undefined) ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
      if (chCode > 31 && (chCode < 48 || chCode > 57))
       return false;
      else
       return true;
     }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="number" class="number" name="number" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event);">
```